# Problem when auto indenting code on shift+enter

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't know about you guys but this is starting to get annoying. There's a problem when you try to keep the indentation using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in a code block.

Having the caret at the end of the line works good.

[image]

---

Having the caret in the middle of the line, not so good.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides fixing the bug that's visible in your first image (the additional empty line before the "enter code here"; this really only happend in very rare cases), I (believe to) have [improved the Shift-Enter behavior](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=46bb422ffaa27b3a2895ff3ce8c31f8b491fa9a9).

From now on, when hitting these keys while the cursor is in the middle of the line, this will split the line at that point, turning the remainder of the line into a new list item / code line. This seems to be the intutively expected behavior.

This goes out with the next build (but you can already test it in the [PageDown demo editor](http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html)).